# d3 selections in event handler: select vs selectAll

Tags: javascript, d3.js, css-selectors

I am observing (to me) unexpected behavior when selecting SVG elements by class in an onclick-handler with D3.js. I'll present a simple working example, and then two JS fiddles to illustrate the problem.

The example contains two `<rect>`. They are supposed to behave like radio-buttons: when clicked the rectangle is exclusively selected. If any other rectangle is already active, it is deactivated. Any active rectangle is stored in a variable `currently_active`.

```
testdata = [
  {
    unique_id: "3-2-1",
    y: 10
  },
  {
    unique_id: "2-3-1",
    y: 40
  }
];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var rects = svg.selectAll(".node").data(testdata);

var currently_active = null;

rects.enter().append("rect")
.attr("x",10)
.attr("y", function(d){return d.y;})
.attr("width", 60)
.attr("height", 20)
.attr("class", function(d){return "node node-"+d.unique_id;})
.on("click", function(d){
    var node_id = d.unique_id;
    console.log(node_id);
    if (currently_active == node_id) return;
    if (currently_active) {
        var thenode = svg.select(".node-"+currently_active);
        thenode.style("fill", null);
        currently_active = null;
    }
    var thenode = svg.select(".node-"+node_id);
    thenode.style("fill", "#d11");

    currently_active = node_id;
});
```

This simple version works as intended. Note: the clicked `node_id`'s are logged into the JS console.

1. Not working as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/bdy8z7dh/1/

   - Here I moved the code into a minimal "reusable chart" function.
   - This version does not work as intended: It does work on the first click event, but then the node_id is undefined in the next event (see the JS console).
   - Note that I saved the "parent" element in a variable as to not use the global `d3.select` in the event callback.
2. Working as intended again: http://jsfiddle.net/bdy8z7dh/2/

   - Here I simply changed the `parent.select` into `parent.selectAll`, and now the example works as intended again.

Another fix is to use the global `d3.select` instead of `parent.select`. But there is something I have not understood: why does not the second fiddle work? What am I missing? It might have something to do with scopes in JS, as the first minimal example works?

PS. My intention was to put all three code snippets in fiddles, but my rep is too low to post several links. I would also like to link to Mike Bostock's article on reusable charts, but for now you can find it by googling "towards reusable charts"

Comment: I haven't looked at this in detail, but suspect that it's because `parent.select(...)` inherits the data from the parent to the child. That is, if `parent` has its data changed and you do `.select()`, the selected element will also have the new data. This *doesn't* happen with `d3.select()` and `.selectAll()`.

Comment: That sounds like a lead, but does it explain that it works on the first click but not on the second? Note that the data is only bound once and only .enter() is ever used. If someone could elaborate (or URL) on the difference @LarsKotthoff mentions I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LarsKotthoff was exactly right in his comment.

You are initializing the elements with the correct data, so the first switch works well. But as soon as you switch away from the first-selected button, the `parent.select` call changes the data on the selected button to the whole data array that was originally only on the parent. However, `parent.selectAll` does not propagate the parent data, so in that case you are fine.

To verify this, I added another console output on line 19 in your examples:

- With `select`: http://jsfiddle.net/bdy8z7dh/12/
- With `selectAll`: http://jsfiddle.net/bdy8z7dh/14/

The relevant documentation section is here https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#select, and it says about `selection.select()`

> If the current element has associated data, this data is inherited by
>   the returned subselection, and automatically bound to the newly
>   selected elements.

and about `selection.selectAll()`

> The subselection does not inherit data from the current selection;
>   however, if the data value is specified as a function, this function
>   will be called with the data d of the ancestor node and the group
>   index i to determine the data bindings for the subselection.

*Edit:*

You are correct in your comment below: Your first example works because you assign the data directly to the `rect` elements so the `svg` element has no data to propagate. `selection.select()` only overwrites data on the subselection if the parent has data.

Comment: Thanks, is the reason that the first simple example inlined in my question works, that the svg does not have any data to propagate?